# SharePoint list formatting clickable link

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, column-formatting

I've create a SharePoint list with clickable image from a link column, more info over here: [SharePoint list formatting image column with clickable link from another column](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/308591/sharepoint-list-formatting-image-column-with-clickable-link-from-another-column/)

Now I'm trying to fix an error, when the link column is empty it's create a faulty link instead of showing no link. I've tried the code below this but hides the image too.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "a",
  "style":{
    "display":  "=if([$MyLinkColumn]=='','none','block'" 
  },
  "attributes": {
    "target": "_blank",
    "href": "[$MyLinkColumn]"
  },
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "img",
      "style": {
        "display": "block",
        "background-color": "none",
        "position": "relative",
        "width": "60px"
      },
      "attributes": {
        "src": "@currentField.serverRelativeUrl"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this JSON on your Image column:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "a",
      "attributes": {
        "target": "_blank",
        "href": "[$Link]"
      },
      "style": {
        "display": "=if([$Link]!='','block','none')"
      },
      "children": [
        {
          "elmType": "img",
          "style": {
            "display": "block",
            "background-color": "none",
            "position": "relative",
            "width": "60px"
          },
          "attributes": {
            "src": "@currentField.serverRelativeUrl"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "elmType": "img",
      "style": {
        "display": "=if([$Link]!='','none','block')",
        "background-color": "none",
        "position": "relative",
        "width": "60px"
      },
      "attributes": {
        "src": "@currentField.serverRelativeUrl"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Where `Link` is the **internal name** of my hyperlink column. You can get the internal name of your column by following this article: [How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/)